# With meson build can I define intra-project dependencies?

Tags: build, build-system, meson-build

Say I'm building targets A, B, and C in one project. In meson, is it possible to define dependency relationships between them?

For example, if the dependency graph looks like this:

```
A -> C
B -> C
```

How could I express this with meson?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible to define intra-project dependencies. I found [this test case](https://github.com/mesonbuild/meson/tree/master/test%20cases/common/85%20internal%20dependency) on github.com to demonstrate how to do it. You can also refer to the section on dependencies in the [manual](https://mesonbuild.com/Dependencies.html).

Say I have a `meson.build` file defining two targets:

```
project('Demonstrate Dependencies', 'cpp')

subdir('src')
subdir('proj')
```

`proj` builds a library that `src` will depend on. Then `proj/meson.build` will look something like this:

```
incdirs = include_directories('include')
proj_lib = static_library('proj', 'proj.c', include_directories : incdirs)

proj_dep = declare_dependency(
      include_directories : incdirs
    , link_with : proj)
```

And `src/meson.build` would look something like:

```
exe = executable('proj_exe', 'main.c', dependencies : proj_dep)
```